# Proof by contradiction and order of statements

Tags: real-analysis, logic, proof-writing

Order matters, take sequences tending towards a limit:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:n>N\implies|x_n-L|<\epsilon$$
"For all $\epsilon$ there exists an $N$" is totally different to "there exists an $N$ such that for all $\epsilon$"

For the first one (I like to think of) $N$ is a function of $\epsilon$, for the second there is an $N$ that is the same regardless of $\epsilon$.

I want to prove that a continuous function on a closed interval takes it's minimum on that interval. ($\exists x\in I:f(x)=m$, m is the inf of the function) I supposed $m<f(x)\forall x\in I$ (how is this different from

$\forall x\in I \text{ (what goes here? it's not such that) } m<f(x)$) I think.

So I have just proved what I thought was "$f(x)>m\forall x\in I$ is false", which means I have shown "(not $f(x)>m\forall x\in I$) is true" which is $f(x)\le m\exists x\in I$

$f(x)<m$ contradicts $m$ being the $\inf$ so this is means I have $f(x)=m\exists x\in I$ - which is good!

So my question is about the order. When I did my proof by contradiction I never said "let x be given" but I did use (and wrote) $m<f(x)\forall x\in I$ which strikes me as different from $\forall x\in I\ m<f(x)$

I'd like to be more confident manipulating, interpreting and using these expressions, please (ideally a PDF!) help me find something.

**Last note**
Say I have two properties, $A$ and $B$ which are true when $C$ is true, that is:
$C\implies A$ and $C\implies B$

is that the same as:

$C\implies [A\text{ and }B]$? If you negate them I'm not sure.

Comment: For your last note, just make a truth table and check.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to say, but note that the very first formula is wrong. It should be $$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\in \mathbb N:n>N\implies|x_n-L|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Well, if you have proved that a continuous function on a closed interval takes it's minimum on that interval, then you've also proved that $1 = 2$ ! Take the interval $\mathbb{R}$ and the function $x$, for example... The interval must be bounded also in general.

Comment: @Amateur I'm not sure that it's correct to say that $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed *interval*, although you're certainly right that it's a closed set.

Comment: @crf It **is** an interval. $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval  if $\forall a,b \in E, \forall c \in \mathbb{R}, a < c < b \Rightarrow c \in E$.

Comment: @Amateur yep. I take it back.

Comment: @GitGud the extra $\forall$ is redundant. I am asserting that if it is true that $n>N$ it is true that $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$, I could say $\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\in\mathbb{N} n>N\ |\  |x_n-L|<\epsilon$, note I said redundant not wrong.

Comment: @AlecTeal It's not redundant. The formula I mentioned (the first one in your question) isn't even a statement, it is devoided of meaning.

Comment: @GitGud don't put yourself down, you're saying "for all e it is true that there exists an N where for all natural n the assertion that when n>N it is true that $x_n$ is within e of L holds". Mine says "for all e it is true that there is an N where the assertion that n>N means $x_n$ is within e from L holds"

Comment: @AlecTeal Be my guest to go on through your mathematical life thinking that is correct.

Comment: @GitGud during my first term, when I was being hit with shovel that is "You know nothing lowly undergrad!" and coming to terms with having chosen to do maths and feeling conned I gave a definition like yours (with the redundant $\forall$) and one of the maths-gods descended from Mt Olympus/grown up common-room explained to me that it was redundant and although I felt bad (like he was humouring me the way you would if a toddler failed a card trick) I learnt a lot. I now realise he was paid and, like me, mortal. But still!

Comment: @GitGud I've got to agree with the OP here. I believe the $\forall$ isn't necessary. It is common practice to omit this quantifier, and this practice can be justified in mathematical logic. See A.G. Hamilton's *Logic for Mathematicians*, Corollary 3.28, p. 64.

Comment: @AlecTeal Never, ever trust analysts when it comes to notation, quantifiers and logic.

Comment: @Amateur There's no need for me to see that. If it's OK in that book, then the author followed a very non-standard way of doing things. Formulae with free variables aren't statements.

Comment: @GitGud it may be my programming with C++ background (strongly typed langauge) but surely $x_n$ implies that $n$ is a natural number, otherwise it wouldn't be defined! Type deduction is one of my strongest tools especially in vector analysis and calculus, if I forget what something is from the types at play I can deduce what it must be, if the notation was ambiguous it would not have come to be common. That is why I said redundant, the extra $\forall$ adds no information. Type analysis got me through linear algebra.

Comment: @GitGud it's also WIDELY used in Abstract Algebra, quite often the binary operation of a group is omitted because the set the group is (right terminology?) could only be a group under a certain operation.

Comment: @AlecTeal $x_n$ would be undefined, my point exactly. Just because there is only one way of things making sense, doesn't mean it is correct. In any case, since the quantifier is missing and I'm given leeway to interpret it, I could very well interpret it an existential quantifier.

Comment: GitGud is right about needing the quantifier $\forall n$. Sometimes, people omit universal quantifiers from the beginning of a statement, for example presenting the commutative law as just $x+y=y+x$ rather than the correct $\forall x\forall y\,(x+y=y+x)$. But omitting a quantifier from the middle of a formula is wrong.

Comment: @GitGud you would be wrong to do so. Having deduced $n$ is natural, and knowing the final part is true when $n>N$ we can see $n\in\{N+1,N+2,...\}$

Comment: @AlecTeal The only sets that "could only be a group under a certain operation" are one-element sets. Any set with two or more elements admits several group operations.

Comment: @AndreasBlass it's not omitted, you can have an implies sign or a $\forall n$ pick one to have no redundant information.

Comment: @GitGud the group $(\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23\},+)$ what could the operation be? Addition modulo 24 from the looks. You could pick an isomorphism though **but it wouldn't matter** (eg 5 and 1 are generators) (pick any number coprime to 24, it's a generator, 5 gives 0,5,10,15,20,1,6,11.... which looks different but it isn't. Group structure is preserved)

Comment: @AlecTeal If you're saying that the presence of either $\forall$ or $\implies$ should be automatically understood to entail the other as well, then I completely disagree. The only notation I'm aware of that bears any resemblance to that idea is the use of subscripts on $\implies$ to indicate the context, but even that is done only when the implicit quantifier governs the whole formula (or rather the whole sequent, since this sort of notation seems to be specific to the sequent calculus).

Comment: @AlecTeal You let the intended meaning cloud what is actually being said. Of course I can interpret all that, but that's because, unfortunately, I can understand wrong things. Just like you.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I don't mean in general in this case we're arguing about the definition of a sequence converging to a limit. The $n>N\implies$ gives the same information as $\forall n\in\{N+1,N+2,...\}$

Comment: The set of integers from 0 to 23 has lots of group structures that are not isomorphic to addition modulo 24.  For example, it has a non-commutative group structure isomorphic to the group of permutations of 4 objects.

Comment: Stackexchange objects to adding more comments, and they don't seem to be doing any good anyway. Everything that needs to be said has been said; it only remains for Alec Teal to listen.

Comment: @AndreasBlass exactly, that is why I didn't pick a prime number (coincidence with 4! being 24, I was going for "24 hours") but with no other context the "+" operator implies some sort of addition, rather than composition (typically a dot). With C++ the compiler will only do 1 implicit cast when it isn't ambiguous, that is because 2 steps is ambiguous. Obviously context helps. We also write "0" for "additive identity" and "1" for multiplicative (when it isn't ambiguous of course) we can deduce we don't mean the natural numbers (not a word about 0 :P) 1 and 0, we mean the identities.